# Why does numba have worse optimization than Cython in this code?

Tags: python, optimization, numba

I am trying to optimize some code with numba. The problem is that a simple Cython optimization (just specifying data types) is six times faster than using autojit, so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

The function to optimize is:

```
from numba import autojit

@autojit(nopython=True)
def get_energy(system, i,j,m): 
  #system is an array, (i,j) some indices and m the size of the array
  up=i-1;  down=i+1;  left=j-1;  right=j+1
  if up<0: total=system[m,j]
  else: total=system[up,j]
  if down>m: total+=system[0,j]
  else: total+=system[down,j]
  if left<0: total+=system[i,m]
  else: total+=system[i,left]
  if right>m: total+=system[i,0]
  else: total+=system[i,right]
  return 2*system[i,j]*total
```

A simple run would be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.random.rand(50,50)
get_energy(x, 3, 5, 50)
```

I've understood that numba is good at loops but may not optimize other things very well. Anyhow, I would expect a similar performance to Cython, is numba slower accessing arrays or at conditional statements?

The .pyx file in Cython is:

```
import numpy as np
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

def get_energy(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] system, int i,int j,unsigned int m): 
  cdef int up
  cdef int down
  cdef int left
  cdef int right
  cdef np.float64_t total
  up=i-1;  down=i+1;  left=j-1;  right=j+1
  if up<0: total=system[m,j]
  else: total=system[up,j]
  if down>m: total+=system[0,j]
  else: total+=system[down,j]
  if left<0: total+=system[i,m]
  else: total+=system[i,left]
  if right>m: total+=system[i,0]
  else: total+=system[i,right]
  return 2*system[i,j]*total
```

Please comment if I need to give further information.

Comment: How are you benchmarking this?

Comment: @delnan I'm using `%timeit` in IPython.

Comment: This may be dealt with in `timeit`, but there's a fairly large initial overhead compiling the numba function the first time it's run. You could add a call to the numba function in the initialization code just to ensure you've done that before you start timing. (I'd guess this will be small and the issue though)

Comment: You may also have some off-by-one indexing errors. Try changing `down>m` to `down>=m` and `total=system[m,j]` to `total=system[m-1,j]` (etc.). I doubt that affects your speed, but it probably will give you exciting bugs. Alternatively you could do `up=(i-1)%m` (i.e. the modulus) and the same for down, left, right. That would let you get rid of all the `if/else`s which might well improve the speed of both numba and Cython.

Comment: @DavidW Thank, I'll have a look at those tips. I've finally made it faster than Cython specifying input data types. In a quick test, it seems that int64 is faster than any intXX. Do have any idea why?

Comment: No real idea why int64 is faster. I'd guess because it's probably the native type (and the native index type) for your processor so no type conversions need to take place, but that really is a guess.